# Nightly build of lazy_static fails on Travis-CI with "compiled by an older version of rustc"

Tags: rust

My code seems to run fine except for a crate which was "compiled by an older version of rustc".

Shortened output:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-1a1baae3.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-8
1.30s$ git clone --depth=50 https://github.com/cpjreynolds/rustty.git cpjreynolds/rustty
Cloning into 'cpjreynolds/rustty'...
rustup: extracting installer
rustup: installing toolchain for 'nightly'
install: creating uninstall script at /home/travis/rust/lib/rustlib/uninstall.sh
install: installing component 'rustc'
install: installing component 'rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
install: installing component 'rust-docs'
install: installing component 'cargo'
    Rust is ready to roll.
0.00s0.00s0.00s$ rustc --version
rustc 1.6.0-nightly (1a2eaffb6 2015-10-31)
$ cargo --version
cargo 0.7.0-nightly (8acff56 2015-10-31)
5.93s$ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
 Downloading winapi-build v0.1.1
 Downloading gag v0.1.6
 Downloading nix v0.4.1
 Downloading lazy_static v0.1.15
 Downloading advapi32-sys v0.1.2
 Downloading bitflags v0.3.2
 Downloading term v0.2.12
 Downloading rand v0.3.11
 Downloading libc v0.1.12
 Downloading tempfile v1.1.1
 Downloading libc v0.2.0
 Downloading winapi v0.2.4
 Downloading kernel32-sys v0.1.4
       Fresh winapi-build v0.1.1
       Fresh lazy_static v0.1.15
       Fresh winapi v0.2.4
       Fresh libc v0.2.0
       Fresh libc v0.1.12
       Fresh bitflags v0.3.2
       Fresh nix v0.4.1
       Fresh kernel32-sys v0.1.4
       Fresh advapi32-sys v0.1.2
       Fresh term v0.2.12
       Fresh rand v0.3.11
       Fresh tempfile v1.1.1
       Fresh gag v0.1.6
   Compiling rustty v0.1.9 (file:///home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty)
     Running `rustc src/lib.rs --crate-name rustty --crate-type lib -g --out-dir /home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug -L dependency=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps --extern nix=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps/libnix-decfdf7b683bd511.rlib --extern term=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps/libterm-c60a08d637b7e6c7.rlib --extern lazy_static=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps/liblazy_static-f3aa6dfcc7c157cc.rlib --extern gag=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps/libgag-71f01cbae2611a97.rlib --extern libc=/home/travis/build/cpjreynolds/rustty/target/debug/deps/liblibc-29adb837ec836726.rlib`
src/lib.rs:20:14: 20:39 error: the crate `lazy_static` has been compiled with an old version of rustc, which is incompatible with this version of rustc [E0514]
src/lib.rs:20 #[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;
```

Why does the lazy_static crate fail when building it using the nightly compiler?

edit: `.travis.yml`

```
language: rust

rust:
    - nightly
    - beta
    - stable

cache:
    directories:
        - target

script:
    - cargo build --verbose
    - cargo test --verbose
    - cargo doc

after_success:
    test $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" &&
    test $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" &&
    test $TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION == "stable" &&
    sh etc/deploy-docs.sh
```

Comment: Whats your `.travis.yml` configuration file look like?

Comment: Have you pushed the `target` folder to your repository?

Comment: @huon , ahh It might be using previous cached directories?

Comment: Yeah, don't cache the `target` directory. Why did you add that to your configuration?